# Azure WebJobs Nuget from version 3.0-beta to 3.0. BlobTriggerAttribute is no longer found

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobssdk

All of Microsoft's documentation is based on 2.2.0 and is years old. I cant not figure out how to use BlobTriggers in 3.0 (full release, non-beta)

The packages included:

```
 PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.1" />
 PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.0" />
```

Now anywhere I use blob triggers, it can't find the attribute and doesn't give me any help in the "Quick Actions and Refactorings":

[image]

It's probably a stupid question, but what do I need to do to get this back up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, they moved all the queues, triggers, etc in to their own extensions. So, in the case of `BlobTriggers`, you also need to install:

```
PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.1" />
```